# Does Hive have an issue with handling small data table Inserts?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I am told that any hive job will consume 32 GB memory or some large amount from the cluster and doing trivial row inserts will cause creation of many small files.

Is this true?

Is using Hive to do inserts of small amounts of data inherently wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Small files can be an issue for Hadoop it self. When you insert individual rows in hive, each row will be saved to different file. It takes few seconds for each insert operation. You can see in the below example. I have inserted 3 rows into hive table and it has created 3 2 byte files. You should avoid inserting small amounts of data in Hive. It can cause issues such as out of memory to the namenode as metadata of the files will be stored in memory.

```
create table testing (t int);
insert into table testing values (1);
insert into table testing values (2);
insert into table testing values (3);

dfs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/testing;
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs          2 2015-12-08 23:59 /apps/hive/warehouse/testing/000000_0
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs          2 2015-12-08 23:59 /apps/hive/warehouse/testing/000000_0_copy_1
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs          2 2015-12-08 23:59 /apps/hive/warehouse/testing/000000_0_copy_2
```

Comment: It will be few bytes for each file. You can have some of the small tables if it is inevitable. But you should avoid inserting thousands of rows using the approach mentioned. You need to merge these small files into larger ones periodically.

Comment: A few bytes per file does not sound like much. And if they can be merged then that seems to reduce the problem. But in running the inserts, is there potential significant hit on the cluster?

Comment: Yes, each insert statement will take few seconds and will run in a separate JVM. It will saturate the resources or waste the resources significantly.

Comment: You have to use either INSERT ... SELECT * FROM or LOAD command.

Comment: how different would the resource impact be between that and the ordinary INSERT?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97357/discussion-between-durga-viswanath-gadiraju-and-user55570).

Comment: NN consume about 150-200 bytes per each block and also it consume 150-200 for each filename and directory so here total consumption of NN memory will be 300-400 bytes.